# Adding ObjectForScripting property to a WebKitBrowser

Tags: c#, webkit

I have added a WebKitBrowser object to my Visual Studio C# 2010 toolbox by following this tutorial:
http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php?p=1

I'm using Windows Forms.

Currently, the WebKitBrowser object does not contain a ObjectForScripting property, and I have found this file where it is added:

https://github.com/scampy/webkitdotnet/blob/master/WebKitBrowser/WebKitBrowser.cs

How can I get the missing property into my webkitbrowser.dll, which is already added to the tooblar? I already have downloaded the whole webkitdotnet project from github but I don't know exactly what to do with all these files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile webkitdotnet project to get new webkitbrowser.dll. By the way - you can only use Visual Studio 2005 (VS C++ 2005)